# Async not displaying results

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-select

I am trying to make my first attempt with Async from react-select and I can't make Async display results, even tho results are there.

[image]

And this is the results from request:

[image]

This is my code:

```
async getData(searchText) {
        let result;
        let url = "https://localhost:44315/api/Article/Paginated?name="
            + searchText
            + "&skip=0&take=10";

        if(searchText != null) {
            await axios.get(url)
                .then(response =>{
                    result = response.data;
                    this.setState({
                        suggestions: result
                    });
                    return this.state.suggestions;
                }).catch(error => {
                    throw error;
                });
        }
    }

getOptionValue = option => {
        console.log(option.name);
        console.log(option.id);
        return {label: option.name, value: option.id};
    };
```

And this is my Async call:

```
<Async
    options={this.state.suggestions}
    loadOptions={this.getData}
    getOptionValue={this.getOptionValue}
/>
```

console.log in getOptionValue function will show all correct values.

I don't get it what am I doing wrong. I want to display "name" values as I type, but on every type it needs to send a new request with getData function.

EDIT: @Robert I have fixed await and this is the new result I am getting (when returning response.data):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to resolve with the options in your getData function.

If you return the promise you awaited you should see the options turn up.

```
async getData(searchText) {
    let result;
    let url = "https://localhost:44315/api/Article/Paginated?name="
        + searchText
        + "&skip=0&take=10";

    if(searchText != null) {
        return axios.get(url)
            .then(response =>{
                result = response.data;
                this.setState({
                    suggestions: result
                });
                return this.state.suggestions;
            }).catch(error => {
                throw error;
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at my edit. Even tho it is intended for Robert Garcia comment, I get the same result with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here:

```
 await axios.get(url)
                .then(response =>{
                    result = response.data;
                    this.setState({
                        suggestions: result
                    });
                    return this.state.suggestions;
```

If you are using async/await it has no sense you use do .then/.catch

Reformat it to:

```
const response =  await axios.get(url);
this.setState({ suggestions: response.data });

return this.state.suggestions;
```

Next, the React state is async so, your `return this.state.suggestions;` if not returning your desired updated state value.

so,

```
  async function getData(searchText) {
    // if you want allow empty search
    if (!searchText && searchText !== '') {
      return;
    }

    let url = `https://localhost:44315/api/Article/Paginated?name=${searchText}&skip=0&take=10`;

    const response = await axios.get(url);

    this.setState({ suggestions: response.data });
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to write in my post, but my state (suggestions) is updating successfully. What I think is a problem is that I miss something in order for results text to be visible in dropdown.

Comment: Your state is updating successfully, what it is not right was the return of this.state.suggestions after the state update.

Comment: If I remove return, I will not get anything in dropdown, just message "no options"

Comment: I think your problem is how to use the Async component

Comment: As I tought. This is my first encounter with it.

Comment: I have wrote a comment with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem. The problem was that Async component expects data with object that contains properties "label" and "value". Since my json didn't contain those properties (keys), Async component couldn't display anything cause he didn't knew what to do with my array of objects. To solve this problem, I just had to create new variable specifically in that function that will remap values I need. This is the answer:

```
async getData(searchText) {
   let result;
   let url = "https://localhost:44315/api/Article/Paginated?name="
       + searchText
       + "&skip=0&take=10";

   let dropdownResult = [];

   if(searchText !== '') {
      return await axios.get(url)
          .then(response =>{
               result = response.data;

               for(let [key] in Object.entries(result)) {
                   dropdownResult.push({
                       label: result[key].name,
                       value: result[key].id
                   })
               }

               this.setState({
                   suggestions: dropdownResult
               });

          return this.state.suggestions;
      }).catch(error => {
          throw error;
      });
}
```

It would be nice if there is some prop in Async component that would let me say "I want 'name' instead of 'label' and 'id' instead of 'value'. I have been searching and neither Async or AsyncSelect components have those properties.

Plus, I have switched to AsyncSelect (from what I understand so far, those are the same components, but AsyncSelect is more understandable for someone who can read that code instead of Async component). This is how my AsyncSelect now looks:

```
<AsyncSelect
     options={this.state.suggestions}
     loadOptions={this.getData}
     onChange={(e) => this.articleSelected(e)}
     isClearable={true}
/>
```

"articleSelected" looks like:

```
articleSelected = (data) => {
    this.setState({
        articleToAdd: data.value
    });
}
```

"articleToAdd" state is something I will use in other logic (for example when I want to update that specific Article".

It is stupid that in their documentation no one says that application will **NOT** work if there is no 'label' and 'value' keys in object.

Comment: There is no note in the documentation because the component can work without `value` and `label` keys in an object. [In my answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57179661/6612182) I have mentioned props which allow for options without `label` and `value` keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a misunderstanding with the `getOptionValue` prop. It is not used to return a complete object. It is used to resolve your option into a single identifier, e.g. a value or an id. So you just have to return the attribute you want to use as the value.

To use another attribute as the label you have to use the corresponding `getOptionLabel` prop which works the same way as the `getOptionValue` prop but for the label.

```
<AsyncSelect
    getOptionValue={option => option.id}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
/>
```

From the [docs](https://react-select.com/props):

> `getOptionValue` `typeof getOptionValue = (option) => string`
>
> Resolves option data to a string to compare options and specify value attributes.

­

> `getOptionLabel` `typeof getOptionLabel = (option) => string`
>
> Resolves option data to a string to be displayed as the label by components.

Answer (score -1):

Await syntax doesnt work like that

Fix it:

```
 try {
   const response = await axios.get(url);
 } catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
 }

 console.log(response);
```